# Meteor: jQuery render template with animation upon click

Tags: jquery, meteor, jquery-animate, iron-router

Upon clicking a class .join-type-heading in authJoinType template, I would like to render (bring into view) the joinForm template. Additionally, I am trying to animate the joinForm like this (see the way it fades in and moves up). http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/kMxqj/13/

Should I nest the joinForm template inside of authJoin template?

HTML:

```
<template name="authJoin">
{{> authJoinType}} // this template displays two boxes with labels 'publisher' and 'reader'
{{> joinForm}} // this to fade into view when either box is clicked
</template>


<template name="authJoinType">
<div class="container join-type">
   <div class="row"> 


    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#">
        <div class="join-type-heading"  value="reader">Reader</div></a>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#">
        <div class="join-type-heading"  value="publisher">Publisher
        </div></a>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
</template>


<template name="joinForm">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="wrapper-auth">
                <form class="form-join">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="first name" required="" autofocus="" />
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="last name" required="" autofocus="" />
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email address" required="" autofocus="" />
                  </form>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</template>
```

client.js for click event (this is fine)

```
Template.authJoinType.events({
'click div.join-type-heading': function(e, tmpl) {
//function to go here....
}
});
```

I attempted to append html within joinForm jquery on click event but this does not work.
eg

```
$('#container').append('<div>....</div>');
```

I'm using mizzao:bootstrap-3 and mizzao:jquery-ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code removes the class that is not clicked and Then renders the join in form with the animation. **Looks SLICK!!** I combined information from users sbking and user3557327.Thank you both!! The only thing remianing is to slide the right div (second col-md-6) to the left if it is clicked.

client.js

```
Template.authJoinType.rendered = function() { //fade out non selected div
  $('div.join-type-heading').on('click',function() {
    $('.join-type-heading').not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(complete){
          $('.join-form').addClass('show'); //references the .show class in css file
       });
   });
  });
};
```

.css

```
.join-form {
 margin-top: 20px;
 opacity: 0;
 position: relative;
 top: 40px;
 transition: opacity 600ms, top 400ms;
 }
.join-form.show {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 0px;
 }
.join-type-heading {
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: #0088cb;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
color: #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

html:

```
<template name="authJoin">
{{> authJoinType}} 
{{> joinForm}} 
</template>


<template name="authJoinType">
 <div class="container join-type">
  <div class="row"> 

   <div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="join-type-heading"  value="reader">Reader</div></a>
   </div> 

   <div class="col-md-6">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="join-type-heading"  value="publisher">Publisher</div></a>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</template>


<template name="joinForm">
 <div class="container join-form"> //.join-form class is added when div in authJoinType is clicked and other div fades out.
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="wrapper-auth">
            <form class="form-join">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="first name" required="" autofocus="" />
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="last name" required="" autofocus="" />
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email address" required="" autofocus="" />
              </form>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a session variable called `showForm`, check if it's true to show the form and set it to true on the click event:

```
<template name="authJoin">
    {{> authJoinType}}
    {{#if showForm }}
        {{> joinForm}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

Template.authJoin.helpers({
    showForm: function() {
        return Session.equals('showForm', true);
    }
});

Template.authJoinType.events({
    'click div.join-type-heading': function(e, tmpl) {
        Session.set('showForm', true);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure about the animation part, but probably doing the same as your example in the rendered function will work:

```
Template.joinForm.rendered = function() {
    $(this.firstNode).animate({opacity: 1, top:0}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I see the logic in this, how can prevent this from toggling? When the user clicks on the div, I would like the form then to remain on the page. As of now, it disappears when the user clicks the div again.

Comment: Just set the variable to true in the click event: `Session.set('showForm', true)`

Answer (score 1):

You should render the template with a regular handlebars include like `{{> joinForm}}` and put the animation in the animated template's rendered callback:

```js
Template.joinForm.rendered = function() {
  var container = this.$('.container');
  container.css({
    opacity: 0,
    position: 'relative'
    top: 20
  }).animate({
    opacity: 1,
    top: 0
  }, 500);
};
```

Note that you can also handle the animation via CSS, which is generally a better option. For example, if you add the class `join-form` to the container:

```
.join-form {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  transition: opacity 500ms, top 500ms;
}

.join-form.show {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0
}
```

```js
Template.joinForm.rendered = function() {
  this.$('.join-form').toggleClass('show');
};
```

Comment: The template performs exactly how I like it to. Now I am just trying to implement this upon clicking the div. :)

Comment: As the other answer mentions, it's probably best to handle displaying the template with a Session variable that is modified when you click the div. This way the user's interaction state will be preserved across hot reloads.

Comment: What about implementing this template dynamically upon click? ie. {{> Template.dynamic template='joinForm'}} and use a helper to set a variable to true similar to how user3557327 described. Or puting the form in the same template as authJoinType

Comment: Why? Just do `{{#if showJoinForm}}{{> joinForm}}{{/if}}` and add a `showJoinForm` helper to your `authJoin` template that just returns `Session.get('showJoinForm');` You only need dynamic templates if you don't know the name of the template that will be rendered until runtime.

Comment: I see, Thanks for explaining. On the click event, I have set Session.set('showJoinForm', true); this is not right though.I don't wish to toggle it as in the example below

Comment: When the route is accessed from a href link from another page, the animation does not perform. Only when the page is refreshed.

Comment: I changed the toggleClass to addClass...see below. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I noticed the effects only take place when the page is either refreshed or the url is typed in. If clicking on the anchor that has a pathFor, the effects of the page where it is directed to do not take place?